# I cannot inherit methods imported via DllImport. What to do?

Tags: c#, interop

I have a parent class with some imported methods like this:

```
class Parent
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
}
```

Then I have another class that inherits from this Parent class

```
class Child : Parent
{
    GetForegroundWindow(); // intellisense cannot find it
}
```

Does that mean I have to create a wrapper method around the imported GetForegroundWindow() method in the parent class in order to inherit and use it in the child class?

Comment: You should be able to call the method from a derived type.  Perhaps it's because you're calling the method directly inside the class, instead of from inside of a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place GetForegroundWindow call inside of some class method, and not directly in the class.

```
class Child : Parent 
{
    void Foo()
    {
        GetForegroundWindow();
    }
}
```